# cakephp routing for order and pagination

Tags: cakephp, sorting, routes

I am trying to do routing for my controller in CakePHP.

My controller is called UserGames.
Default CakePHP sort code:

```
<?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('price'); ?>
```

By default, sorting links look like this: `userGames/index/sort:name/direction:asc`

I have added the following routing rules:

```
Router::connect('/games', array('controller' => 'UserGames', 'action' => 'index'));
Router::connect('/games/:sort/:direction', array('controller' => 'UserGames'));
```

With those the sorting links produce a URL like this: `games/name/asc`

Sorting does not work this way and $this->PassedArgs is empty. What could my mistake be?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the named parameters to be available as passed arguments in passedArgs, you need to supply a third parameter to your second Router::connect call.

```
Router::connect('/games/:sort/:direction',
    array('controller' => 'UserGames'),
    array('pass' => array('sort', 'direction')));
```

In this case, `$this->passedArgs[0]` will be the sort value and `$this->passedArgs[1]` will be the direction value.

See [the CakePHP docs](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#Router%3a%3aconnect) for more info.

Comment: yes, but how to tell cake php to pass this args into paginator?

Comment: For Paginator to pick them up, they have to be either named or query string params. Since you're getting rid of the named params, I'm not sure if there's a way to do it with named params. But you might be able to convert them to query string params. You could try `'?' => array('sort', 'direction')` instead of `'pass'` but I don't know for sure if it will pick up the values. If you do this, you'll have to specify `'paramType' => 'querystring'` when you set up `$paginate`. See [this](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/pagination.html#pagination-with-get-parameters).